# Can't execute sql query for crystal report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer

> I have some code for execute crystal report into my crystal report viewer, i had been set the parameter and sql, but nothing show up. can anybody help me? I am new in using crystal reports

```
Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Load
    Dim crDatabase As Database
    Dim crTables As Tables
    Dim crTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
    Dim crTableLogOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo
    vRptED.Load("D:\FENNY\ReportsRecon\ReportRecon\Rp11\Revisi\BLReports7RevTrial.rpt")
    crConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
    crDatabase = vRptED.Database
    crTables = crDatabase.Tables

    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = "172.24.34.57"
        .UserID = "sa"
        .Password = "sa"
        .DatabaseName = "REPORTS"
    End With

    crDatabase = vRptED.Database
    crTables = vRptED.Database.Tables

    For Each crTable In crTables
        crTableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
        crTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogOnInfo)
    Next
    connString()
    Dim sql As SqlCommand
    sql = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from PLSummary51 ", con)
    Dim ddlValues1 As SqlDataReader
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ddlValues1 = sql.ExecuteReader
    While ddlValues1.Read
        vRptED.SetParameterValue("BisnisUnit", "51")
        vRptED.SetParameterValue("CompID", "22")
    End While        
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = vRptED
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you opened the connection?

Comment: yes, i have open it. i use method connString. The code stop in vRptED.Database.Tables. N i have already test using crDatabase.Table, n it still no working. It return null or object reference bla bla bla